# Kotlin: Set text with query result in Amplify DataStore

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, aws-amplify

I am obtaining the height data of a user through a query in Amplify's DataStore as follows:

```
val username = Amplify.Auth.currentUser.username
        Log.i("Username actual",username)
        var height = 0
        var original = listOf(height)
        Amplify.DataStore.query(
            Users::class.java,
            { items ->
                while (items.hasNext()) {
                    val item = items.next()
                    Log.i("Email", item.email)
                    Log.i("User", username)
                    if (item.email == username){
                        Log.i("Altura",item.height.toString())
                        height = item.height
                        original = original + height

                    }
                }
                Log.i("HEight final", original.last().toString())
                binding.tvheightUser.setText(original.last().toString())
            },
            { failure -> Log.e("Tutorial", "Could not query DataStore", failure) }
        )
```

As seen in the next line:

```
binding.tvheightUser.setText(original.last().toString())
```

I am trying to save in my text field the last value of the array of heights obtained. However, I can't display the data in my text field.
The data is obtained correctly as verified in the following line:

```
Log.i("HEight final", original.last().toString())
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Could not query DataStore
    DataStoreException{message=Error in querying the model., cause=android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views., recoverySuggestion=See attached exception for details.}
        at com.amplifyframework.datastore.storage.sqlite.SQLiteStorageAdapter.lambda$query$4$com-amplifyframework-datastore-storage-sqlite-SQLiteStorageAdapter(SQLiteStorageAdapter.java:382)
        at com.amplifyframework.datastore.storage.sqlite.SQLiteStorageAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:10)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8557)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.requestLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1353)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3605)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1643)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3605)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25126)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:9723)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6301)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6129)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6081)
        at ficade.app.ui.PerfilFragment.settingHeight$lambda-0(PerfilFragment.kt:60)
        at ficade.app.ui.PerfilFragment.$r8$lambda$c-KDQKF9B3W3xW1gVqmOvgj3sMo(Unknown Source:0)
        at ficade.app.ui.PerfilFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.accept(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.amplifyframework.datastore.storage.sqlite.SQLiteStorageAdapter.lambda$query$4$com-amplifyframework-datastore-storage-sqlite-SQLiteStorageAdapter(SQLiteStorageAdapter.java:380)
        at com.amplifyframework.datastore.storage.sqlite.SQLiteStorageAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:10)
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: What you have looks correct... how do you set up the binding?

Comment: private lateinit var binding: FragmentPerfilBinding and in the onCreateView binding = FragmentPerfilBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) and return binding.root @TylerV

Comment: I added log error in question @TylerV

Comment: @TylerV runOnUiThread works perfect for me. If you want to publish it as an official answer to my question, I can accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your callback to the DataStore query is not running on the main/UI thread, so you get an error from editing views off the UI thread. To fix that, you can wrap the view editing calls in either `runOnUiThread` or use a coroutine on the main thread (using `Dispatchers.Main`)

```kotlin
activity.runOnUiThread {
    binding.tvheightUser.setText(original.last().toString())
}
```

or

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    binding.tvheightUser.setText(original.last().toString())
}
```